# How do I deploy a GWT app in an embedded web server

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to use GWT as a GUI for a stand-alone app (distributed preferably as a single jar).

It would have to have an embedded web server so that when the app is running you could connect to it directly (It could even launch the browser to it's own port on localhost or something).

This doesn't seem too technically challenging, but I could imagine it being a nightmare to get the configuration right.

Is there a project that does this already?  A little embedded HTML server that knows just enough to return the compiled GWT code to a web browser from the current Jar with minimal configuraiton?

Edit:

If there isn't a pre packaged solution out there, any ideas on a good embedded server and how to get it to read files from a jar? (actually it's own jar)

Comment: FYI, [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit) does this already: a GWT app within an embedded web server

Comment: @ThomasBroyer It seems to be deployed as a war.  Does it actually act as both a war and a jar, allowing you run it with the -jar command then opening itself as a war for the web stuff?  If so that's pretty cool, but I never really considered running a .war from the java -jar command line (AND I don't know of an embedable web server that handles war packaging, but I haven't looked at many yet).

Comment: The war embeds a server that's launched from Main-Class  declared in the META-INF, so you can run it just like a jar. I don't think it then loads the web app "as" a war though. Hudson/Jenkins do that too (but are not GWT apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compilation of an GWT application the output is just a bunch of static html, javascript and image files. Those can be deployed to any kind of web server even to an embedded enviroment.

A jar file would require a java container, which can actually limit the possibilities for you. There might be platforms where no jre exist.

I have used Apache during the development to test the compiled code and then deployed to an embedded environment which uses httpd (I think, but not really sure). It wasn't really interesting as it just worked. There where issues/limitations with the embedded browser, but that's a different story.

Comment: What I want is to use this as the GUI for a java app. For the java app to run a JVM must be present.  The embedded server would have no other purpose.  I know it can be done, I was just wondering if either there was a plug and play solution.  It could probably be done within maven, at least mostly.